# How to calculate the transition probability to one bin in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability

I'm having trouble determining the probability of transitions to a bin in MatLab.

I have two long sequences of x,y coordinates:

```
-73.9613487200000   -46.5918895000000
-74.3247836300000   -46.3739157100000
-74.1687114000000   -45.9507475300000
-74.0608490800000   -45.7491954000000
-74.1341642000000   -45.0915414400000
-73.8393784300000   -44.6707425700000
-73.8145227800000   -44.4084257500000
-74.5435599500000   -43.7561156500000
-74.2601082600000   -43.3275746200000
-74.5393861400000   -42.6844697600000
-74.1746965800000   -42.4732404300000
-73.8951934100000   -42.1678074600000
-73.7448163600000   -41.7981857300000
-73.4435398100000   -41.8730435200000
....
```

with the goal of determining the probability of transitioning to a bin (e.g., x>90 x<100 & y>90 y<100) from any previous bin. To be clear, I'd like to eventually create a matrix of probability values in every 10x10 bin.

Defining the bin size and sorting the data is easy enough

```
xbins = -100:10:100;
ybins = -100:10:100;
xNumBins = numel(xbins); yNumBins = numel(ybins);
```

but mostly I may be having a problem with indexing.

Thank you for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to start with you need to transform you `data` matrix to a binned data matrix, `B` (or basically just bin all the data). You can do it like this:

```
bins = -100:10:100;
B = arrayfun(@(x)find(x<=bins,1,'first')-1,data);
```

Now you need to count the transistions and create a grid. You can do this simply by going `T = accumarray(B,1)` but for understanding here is is as a for loop:

```
n = numel(bins)-1;
T = zeros(n);
for k = 1:size(B,1)
    T(B(k,1),B(k,2)) = T(B(k,1),B(k,2)) + 1;
end
```

and then to convert from this sort of joint histogram to a probability matrix

```
T = T/sum(T(:))
```

example:

```
a = rand(10,2)

a =

    0.0534    0.1632
    0.8664    0.4751
    0.3270    0.6687
    0.2016    0.4313
    0.8158    0.6065
    0.8493    0.4217
    0.3997    0.3960
    0.5845    0.1684
    0.5499    0.3672
    0.5886    0.4045
```

and

```
bins = 0:0.2:1;
```

do the calc:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x)find(x<=bins,1,'first')-1,data);
T = accumarray(B,1,[numel(bins)-1, numel(bins)-1])/size(B,1);

T =

    0.1000         0         0         0         0
         0    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000         0
    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0    0.2000    0.1000         0
```

which is correct. You can see that 20% of the data transition from bin 5 to bin 3 for example and that corresponds to rows 2 and 6 from my `a` matrix above.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dan. I could only do this in a sort of long, convoluted way with Excel. This is 1000x faster. I thought ACCUMARRAY was the best route but kept failing. Didn't even think to try a loop.

Comment: @sndsnd Turns out using `accumarray` for this couldn't be simpler! See my edit. However the for loop is probably pretty good and may even be better, with new releases of Matlab it's hard to tell without benchmarking but the loops are generally really fast these days so long as you preallocate.

Comment: Apparently I didn't know how to use `accumarray`. That's very simple. Trying both methods, with my 100000 row dataset, there doesn't seem to be a distinguishable difference in speed. Maybe the loop is better for my learning. Thank you, Dan.